# dafny how to apply trigger

Tags: triggers, dafny

I have read  the very helpful ([Dafny: What does no terms found to trigger on mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398650/dafny-what-does-no-terms-found-to-trigger-on-mean)) but can any one tell me how to prove the two assertions marked with /**/.

Not even sure if they can be proven. The logically equivalent assertions with the defined function `inters` are proven and may be that is as far as you can go.  Any insight greatly appreciated.

```
    function inters(a:set<int>, b:set<int>): set<int> {a*b}
method pingo(a:set<int>, b:set<int>) 
  {     
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in inters(a , b) ) <==> (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in  a*b)           <==> (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in inters(a , b) )) <==> 
             (forall x:int  :: (x in a ==> x!in b ));
/**/ assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in  a*b))        <==> 
             (forall x:int  :: (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     
     assert  ((a*b) == {}) <==> (forall x:int  ::(x in a ==> x!in b )) ;
     assert  ((a*b) == {})  ==> (forall x:int  :: (x !in  inters(a , b) ));
/**/ assert  ((a*b) == {})  ==> (forall x:int  :: (x !in  a*b )) ;
 }
```

Comment: Your file verifies on my machine (except for some trigger warnings, which you can ignore until they bite you later). What version of Dafny and Z3 are you using?

Comment: I'll also give a little mini answer here: the problem is that intersection (`*`) is not allowed to be a trigger. For some of your quantifiers, that means there are no allowed triggers, which means that Dafny/Z3 will have trouble using these quantified facts. When using set union/intersection under quantifiers, I recommend either wrapping them in a function like you did, or expanding them (as in `x in a && x in b` instead of `x in a*b`).

Comment: if you figured it out, can you post a self-answer? if not, let us know what you're still stuck on.

Comment: Slowly I am getting to understand the idea behind triggers but am far from fluent in using them.  Having a history of using natural deduction and isabelle HOL I feel these offer a more solid ground on which I can construct proofs. This may simply be familiarity I will not be able to tell for quite some time. But at the moment I am left "grouping in the dark".  It may be that the HOL-Boogie work will offer an alternative but at the moment teaching prevents me from exploring this avenue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer comes a bit later and indeed does not offer anything new, but I coded the original problem (the same code as David Streader but where all the
`inters(a,b)` have been substituted by `a*b`) and the solution (all the `a*b` replaced by `inters(a,b)`). Just if someone wants to play:

Original problem (full of warnings):

```
function inters(a:set<int>, b:set<int>): set<int> {a*b}

method pingo(a:set<int>, b:set<int>) 
  {     
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in (a*b) ) <==> (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in  a*b)           <==> (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in a*b )) <==> 
             (forall x:int  :: (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in  a*b))        <==> 
             (forall x:int  :: (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     
     assert  ((a*b) == {}) <==> (forall x:int  ::(x in a ==> x!in b )) ;
     assert  ((a*b) == {})  ==> (forall x:int  :: (x !in  a*b ));
     assert  ((a*b) == {})  ==> (forall x:int  :: (x !in  a*b )) ;
 }
```

Solution (no warnings):

```
function inters(a:set<int>, b:set<int>): set<int> {a*b}

method pingo(a:set<int>, b:set<int>) 
  {     
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in inters(a , b) ) <==> (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in  inters(a , b) )           <==> (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in inters(a , b) )) <==> 
             (forall x:int  :: (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     assert  (forall x:int  :: (x !in  inters(a , b) ))        <==> 
             (forall x:int  :: (x in a ==> x!in b ));
     
     assert  ((a*b) == {}) <==> (forall x:int  ::(x in a ==> x!in b )) ;
     assert  ((a*b) == {})  ==> (forall x:int  :: (x !in  inters(a , b) ));
     assert  ((a*b) == {})  ==> (forall x:int  :: (x !in  inters(a , b)  )) ;
 }

//
```

So in this case, if we take James Wilcox's answer, only the first suggestion can be used (wrap the `forall...` in a function). That's because here is no case where we can apply the ‘expansion’, because there are only cases like `x!in ...`, and `x!in inters(a,b)` is not the same as `x!in (a) && x!in(b)`.