# Trigger Dafny with multisets

Tags: triggers, z3, theorem-proving, dafny, multiset

This lemma verifies, but it raises the warning `Not triggers found`:

```
lemma multisetPreservesGreater (a:seq<int>, b:seq<int>, c:int, f:int, x:int)
       requires |a|==|b| && 0 <= c <= f + 1 <= |b| 
       requires (forall j :: c <= j <= f ==> a[j] >= x)
       requires multiset(a[c..f+1]) == multiset(b[c..f+1])
       ensures (forall j :: c <= j <= f ==> b[j] >= x)
{

       assert (forall j :: j in multiset(a[c..f+1]) ==> j in multiset(b[c..f+1]));

}
```

I do not know how to instantiate this trigger (cannot instantiate it as a function, or can I?). Any help?

Edit: Maybe I can instantiate a method f such that takes an array and inserts it in a multiset, and therefore I can trigger f(a), but that does not mention i. I will try.

Comment: If your program verifies, you can safely ignore this warning. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398650/dafny-what-does-no-terms-found-to-trigger-on-mean).

Comment: Completely, my concern in this case is that I would like to know how to manually select the trigger for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to transform the program so that there are no trigger warnings.

```
function SeqRangeToMultiSet(a: seq<int>, c: int, f: int): multiset<int>
  requires 0 <= c <= f + 1 <= |a|
{
  multiset(a[c..f+1])
}

lemma multisetPreservesGreater (a:seq<int>, b:seq<int>, c:int, f:int, x:int)
       requires |a|==|b| && 0 <= c <= f + 1 <= |b| 
       requires (forall j :: c <= j <= f ==> a[j] >= x)
       requires multiset(a[c..f+1]) == multiset(b[c..f+1])
       ensures (forall j :: c <= j <= f ==> b[j] >= x)
{
       assert forall j :: j in SeqRangeToMultiSet(a, c, f) ==> j in SeqRangeToMultiSet(b, c, f);
       forall j | c <= j <= f
        ensures b[j] >= x
       {
        assert b[j] in SeqRangeToMultiSet(b, c, f);
       }
}
```

The point is that we introduce the function `SeqRangeToMultiSet` to stand for a subexpression that is not a valid trigger (because it contains arithmetic). Then `SeqRangeToMultiSet` itself can be the trigger.

The downside of this approach is that it decreases automation. You can see that we had to add a `forall` statement to prove the postcondition. The reason is that we need to mention the trigger, which does not appear in the post condition.

Comment: Whoa, thanks a lot, that is the idea I was suggesting on my Edit. However, that last `forall` with `ensures` is a mind-blow for me, and have never seen it. Did not know that `::` could be replaced with `|` either. There is always something new to know about Dafny, maybe I should read a complete manual. As always, lots of thanks, mate :)

Comment: yeah, there are a ton of features :) the "forall statement" is definitely a good one to know